# Is there a way to overwrite defines from different files?

Tags: php, wordpress, require

I'm trying to make an interface for updating all instances of a WordPress plugin on a server that hosts 20+ WordPress sites. I've got everything working except for the fact that I have a loop with:

```
require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');
require_once($path.'/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
require_once($path.'/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php');
```

where `$path` is equal to a website directory (`$path` changes with every iteration of my loop).

The reason I need to require the files this way is because `wp-load.php` includes (among other things) a file called `wp-config.php`, which defines things like the SQL database, which is different between each website.

**TL&DR** and stating my actual question:

Is there any way for me to do something like the following code?

```
require_once("dir1/a.php"); // define("VAR","dir1");
echo VAR; // displays "dir1"
unrequire_once("dir1/a.php");

require_once("dir2/a.php"); // define("VAR","dir2");
echo VAR; // displays "dir2"
```

Comment: I suppose, the problem is not in `require_once` itself, cause paths are different. You need to cancel `define`.

Comment: @kirilloid Now that I look at it, you're absolutely right. Let me fix up my question.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do that. In one script. You may change your script to run one php script per site, via `exec` or somewhat.

Comment: @kirilloid Efficiency isn't terribly important because this will be a strictly in-house tool, so I would use this approach if I had to. The only alternative I can think of is dynamic name-spacing, which doesn't appear to be possible in PHP yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned this is an in-house tool, you could consider using runkit in order to remove the constant at runtime, allowing it to be redefined later: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-remove.php

---

Afraid not - even if you could, you wouldn't get the behaviour you're looking for because constants (`define`) can only be created once, and are like that for the rest of execution. They cannot be removed, or changed thereafter.

Unfortunately, you're going to have to re-architect your script (e.g. to use variables instead of constants).

Comment: You forgot the second "t" in "constant" in your link. And that's an interesting library. I'll look into it if no better alternative is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: fork the process. You can do something like:

```
foreach ($pathlist as $path) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if(!$pid) {
        require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');
        require_once($path.'/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
        break;
    }
}
```

This will create a copy of your script for each $path in your list and gets around the require_once problem.

You need to "break" the loop if it's a child, as you only want the child process to run for its individual $path setting and not continue the loop itself!